# E2010 Incompatible types: 'HWND' and 'TWindowHandle'

Tags: delphi

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Edit, FMX.Controls.Presentation, Windows, IOUtils;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  Res : Integer;
begin
  Res := MessageBox(
    Self.Handle
    , PChar('Сообщение в окне диалога.')
    , PChar('Заголовок окна')
    , MB_YESNOCANCEL + MB_ICONINFORMATION
    );

  case Res of
    IDYES : begin
      //Действия в случае, когда пользователь нажал кнопку "Да".
    end;
    IDNO : begin
      //Действия в случае, когда пользователь нажал кнопку "Нет".
    end;
    IDCANCEL : begin
      //Действия в случае, когда пользователь нажал кнопку "Отмена".
    end;
  end;
end;
end.
```

The following errors occur :

> [dcc64 Error] Unit1.pas(34): E2010 Incompatible types: 'HWND' and 'TWindowHandle'
>
> [dcc64 Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(6): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Self.handle` in FMX is not HWND type. you should use the `Wnd` property of `WindowHandleToPlatform()`  for converting TWindowHandle to HWND.
so part of your code will look like this:

```
...
Res := MessageBox(
    WindowHandleToPlatform(Self.Handle).Wnd
    , PChar('Сообщение в окне диалога.')
    , PChar('Заголовок окна')
    , MB_YESNOCANCEL or MB_ICONINFORMATION
    );
```

**Update 1**:
 the `WindowHandleToPlatform` function is in `FMX.Platform.Win` unit. you should add it to the uses clause.

**Update 2:**
as  @andreas-rejbrand mentioned in comments, use `or` instead of `+` for combining flags

Comment: Also, don't combine flags using `+`; instead, use `or`.

Comment: (And since you only pass string literals to the `MessageBox` function, you can omit the `PChar` casts if you like.)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `FormToHWND(Self)` instead of `WindowHandleToPlatform(Self.Handle).Wnd`. `FormToHWND()` is also in the `FMX.Platform.Win` unit.

Comment: What's the reverse of this? How to get HWND to be TWindowHandle?